# Tikz "scope line" style for description node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to model the style of the descriptive annotations shown in this image:

[image]

There are several features I want to have:

1. Orthogonal lines
2. Color
3. Circles at the end of lines to be placed at specific locations in the document (either to annotate figure or some text)
4. A vertical line spanning the height of the text descriptions (a "scope line" of sorts) to which the orthogonal lines connect perpendicularly (with the ability to position the intersections at different points on the line)

I have a basic understanding of how to get 1, 2, and 3, which I will demonstrate in my MWE below, but 4 is giving me some trouble. I have considered using the `decorations.pathreplacing` feature, but am only able to get curly braces, not straight lines (and I can't seem even to get the curly braces positioned quite right, in case I want to use those, too, as another option).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (8,8); % just to get something on the page
\node (n1) at (7,2) [anchor=west,text width=3cm] {Some description about something};
\draw [-{Circle},color=ForestGreen] (n1.west) -| (5,4);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2pt,mirror,raise=0pt},color=ForestGreen] (n1.north west) ++(3pt,0) coordinate (s) -- (n1.south west -| s);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which renders:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already draws the line from the node to the object. You can draw the needed border with the same command:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (8,8); % just to get something on the page
\node[text width=3cm, align=left, anchor=west] (n1) at (7,2) {Some description about something};
\draw [-{Circle},color=ForestGreen] (n1.north west) -- (n1.south west) (n1.west) -| (5,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Update:

`inner ysep=0pt` can be fixed to adjust the lateral bar to the text and some vertical `shifting` can be used to move the intersection point above or below the center.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (8,8); % just to get something on the page
\node[text width=3cm, align=left, anchor=west, inner ysep=0pt] (n1) at (7,2) {Some description about something};
\draw [-{Circle},color=ForestGreen] (n1.north west) -- (n1.south west) ([yshift=2mm]n1.west) -| (5,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see! Two more questions: (1) How would I fine-tune the height of the vertical line? I don't want it to extend beyond the text height. (2) How do I adjust the intersection of the two lines as in the example image in my original post? Thanks.

Comment: @Roy I've answered your extra questions in the second example.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.